# undefined index logical error in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

hy!
this is my html code....

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add New Templete</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php include 'side.php'; ?>
    <div class="main">
    <h2>Add New Templete</h2>
    <form method="post" action="add.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table border="1px solid">
        <tr>
        <td>Templete Name:</td><td><input type="text" name="temp_name"></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Templete Category</td><td><input type="text" name="category"></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Templete Image</td><td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Templete Discription</td><td><input type="text" name="decp"></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Templete Quantity</td><td><input type="text" name="qty"></td></tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Templete Price</td><td><input type="text" name="price"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        <td>    
        <input type="submit" value="ADD">
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my php code

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$name=$_POST['temp_name'];
$cat=$_POST['category'];
$image=$_POST['image'];
$desc=$_POST['decp'];
$qty=$_POST['qty'];
$price=$_POST['price'];
$qry="INSERT INTO templetes(templete_name,category,image,description,quantity,price)VALUES('$name','$cat','$image','$desc','$qty','$price')";
$res=mysql_query($qry,$con);
if($res)
{

    echo "record inserted";
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Every thing are fine the data will be stored in database but the image are not stored in database, it says "undefined index image on ....... line ...." means it will show the undefined index error. all the  data will stored except the image?

Comment: What are you trying to store in the database?  `image` is a file, so its information is stored in `$_FILES`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: P.S. This code is *horribly unsafe*, please don't actually use it on a real website.  You should switch from the deprecated `mysql_*` functions to either MySQLi or PDO.  You should also learn about "prepared statements", which is currently the safest way to run SQL queries with user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$image=$_FILES['image'];
```

Comment: `$_FILES['image']` is an array, just FYI.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $_POST['image'];
```

you can't get file in $_POST please use

```
 $_FILES['image']
```

And as you are inserting the image into a table, so it has to be converted to binary from string. Here is the solution for you-

connection.php

```
<?php
 $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "todo");
 if (!$con) {
echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
exit;
 }
?>
```

and add.php

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$name=$_POST['temp_name'];
$cat=$_POST['category'];
$image=$_FILES['image'];
$desc=$_POST['decp'];
$qty=$_POST['qty'];
$price=$_POST['price'];
$imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));;
$qry="INSERT INTO     templetes(templete_name,category,image,description,quantity,price)VALUES('$name'   ,'$cat','{$imgData}','$desc','$qty','$price')";
$res=mysqli_query($con,$qry);
if($res)
{
   echo "record inserted";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

remember data type of the image field in the database should be BLOB or Large BLOB.but remember this is not the safest or coolest way to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['image'];` you can't get file in `$_POST`
please use

```
$_FILES['image']
```

Also, you should use `move_uploaded_file` function to move the uploaded file on server dir.

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], './you_dir_path'.$_FILES['image']['name'])
```

Comment: `$_FILES['image']` is an array, just FYI.